# object reference not set to an instance of an object (C++/CLI)

Tags: c++, c++-cli, null-pointer

In the code below i get this error: object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
public ref class UtilityFunction
{
    UtilityFunction(void)
    {
        temp = 2;
    }

    public:
    int temp;

    public: void runTest()
    {
        int tmp = this -> temp;   //this line gets error
    }
};
```

it is called within another class:

```
public ref class Startup : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{

private: void foo()
    {
        UtilityFunction^ utilityfunc;
        utilityfunc->runTest();
    }
};
```

when running in the line "int tmp = this -> temp;" this is an undefined value!

why is that so? whats wrong?

Comment: You didn't initialize `utilityfunc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UtilityFunction^ utilityfunc = gcnew UtilityFunction();
utilityfunc->runTest();
```

You need to create class instance before using it.

Comment: Oops! yeah i forgot it :|